How to rewrite query string in .htaccess
What I would like is that I would like to rewrite this url
https://www.example.com/newsite/it/categories?sector=1
into something like this:
https://www.example.com/newsite/it/products/industry-sector
I have already tried this rewrite rule in the .htaccess
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sector=1$
RewriteRule ^newsite/it/products$ /newsite/it/products/industry-sector [R=301,L]

But the url does not undergo any change
I thought it might also depend on other rewrite rules I have, so I'll leave you the whole .htaccess file, maybe it can be helpful (if you also have advice on the rules already in place are always welcome):
.HTACCESS
RewriteEngine on

# Reindirizzamento alla radice del sito in base alla lingua della cartella
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (it) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /newsite/it/index [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (en) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /newsite/en/index [L,R=301]
# Reindirizzamento predefinito
RewriteRule ^$ /newsite/it/index [L,R=301]



# Rimuovi l'estensione .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sector=1$
RewriteRule ^newsite/it/products$ /newsite/it/products/industry-sector [R=301,L]


# Reindirizza tutte le altre richieste alla radice del sito
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/newsite
RewriteRule (.*) /newsite/$1 [L]

I thank in advance anyone who will help me :)

You attempt expects a query string in the incoming request (RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sector=1$), yet you say you do not want that to be the case. That condition prevents your rule from getting applied.

The issue is that without such query string the rewriting engine has absolutely no means to know what sector id to rewrite the incoming request to. Unless you are not looking for a general rule but for one specific only for this very sector.

That is a general thing people need to understand what starting to rewrite URLs. You somehow need to have that sector id inside your URL, or you need to find the correct sector inside your application logic not by id but by name, which usually is very inefficient. What people usually do in that situation is to use URL that do actually contain the id, in this case it would be something like that: /newsite/it/products/1/industry-sector. Such a URL would carry all required information necessary for rewriting, yet it looks "pretty" and makes sense for SEO scoring.

okay so if I understand correctly, you are advising me to leave the id in the url and simply make it more “pretty”

Yes anyway I was looking for a specific rule for this sector in fact 1 for me equals industrial sector and 2 equals water sector

If you are looking for a very specific rule for this only category then no, then you can simply hard code the ID in the rewriting rule. Which is not possible in a general rule which is what people usually are looking for.

I tried to sum things up in an answer below. Probably things won't work with that out of the box, it is just meant to push you into the right direction. In the end you won't get around having to test, but more important to understand what the different rules do exactly .

In the comments to the question you confirmed that you are looking for a specific rule for only one such category. That means you can hard code the required ID in the rule itself. Which makes things easy.
It appears however that you miss understood how rules work. Your rule need to match the incoming requested URL, so the "pretty" URL. That might be a starting point for you:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?newsite/it/products/industry-sector$ /newsite/it/categories?sector=1 [L]

The other way round, changing the outgoing content you deliver to requesting clients is nothing that should be done by means of rewriting. Because rewriting only gets applied to incoming requests. Which means the client has to make two requests. One for the old URL, then it gets redirected and has to make a second request to fetch the new, pretty URL. That is highly inefficient. There are other means beside rewriting that allow to manipulate the content you send out, for example links embedded in that. But usually that is a bad idea. Instead you should alter your application to use the pretty link in the first place.
There are situations however where one needs to redirect such "old" URL. For example if such URLs exist in google searches or third party sites. Then this might be the right approach:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sector=1$
RewriteRule ^/?newsite/it/categories$ /newsite/it/products/industry-sector  [R=301,L]

Note that you used a different matching pattern (^newsite/it/products$) which won't work on the incoming requests. .
